# Excel importing from CSV adding additional column

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

Hi I have a CSV file and the first field is date.
I'm imprting this csv file using Data->Import from Text
When I do that it's adding an additional column at the left.
I do not want it to add additional column what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just delete the column by selecting it (clicking on the column header `A`) and then `right click -> Delete` ?

If it's not the case, I think you would have to do a kind of processing on your .csv file, either using `sed` (on linux) or open it with an advanced text editor (more advances than notepad) and do a search an repalce with regex; replacing `^[^;]*;` with nothing (blank).
This would remove everything at the beginning of the line until the `;` character (assuming that your csv delimiter is `;`... if not, replace every occurence of semicolon with your delimiter)

I might be able to help you a little more if you provide an example of your CSV data.